# Does an std::optional parameter create a copy?

Tags: c++, reference, copy, option-type, optional-parameters

I have a function that takes an std::optional

`void foo(const std::optional<T>& opt);`

But copying `T` is expencive.

Does this create a copy of `T`?

If so, how can I not create a copy?

Comment: It can't create a copy if you don't call it. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It really depends on how you call the function.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const T>>` instead.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ok, I call it like `foo({t});` where `t` is what I don't want to copy.

Comment: @StoryTeller Wow, I didn't know that existed. Thanks :) I think that's what I want.

Comment: Let's be mature please and not lash out at those who told you what's wrong with your post. Your question lacks a proper [mcve], there is no definitive answer for it. My comment was just a guess at best. If you want to avoid downvotes, focus on making your posts of high quality.

Comment: @StoryTeller You're right StoryTeller. I just don't appreciate the unhelpful jokes. Instead of asking "How are you calling the function?", Juan had to be a funny guy.

In retrospect, my question should have been "Does std::optional hold a copy" and I could have tested it myself by making a constructor that prints something. I still think my frustration is justified though.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, std::optional stores a copy of whatever you pass to it. The C++17 standard explicitly prohibits storing references in std::optional. See: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional#:~:text=There%20are%20no%20optional%20references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional#:%7E:text=There%20are%20no%20optional%20references)

As suggested by others, passing `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const T>>` is one way to avoid making copies.

```
void foo(const std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const T>>& opt) {
  if (opt) {
    // Do something.
  }
}

T t;
foo(t);
```

But consider that the C++ committee had good reasons for disallowing references in std::optional. For instance, an "optional reference" essentially describes what a plain pointer does, and plain pointers don't suffer from the long type name.

```
void foo(const T* opt) {
  if (opt) {
    // Do something.
  }
}

T t;
foo(&t);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you will find useful [this documentation page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/performance_considerations.html). See the section about "Optional function parameters".

When you call the function and pass an instance of T, an optional will be constructed which will own its own copy of T, therefore it will call T's copy constructor.

```
int main()
{
  T t;
  optional<T> ot;
  foo(t);  // will create a copy
  foo(ot); // won't create a copy
}
```

---

If you're using `boost::optional`, ***not** `std::optional`*, you can declare foo as receiving an optional reference, i.e.

```
void foo(boost::optional<const T&> t)
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the read. I should have used `sizeof` to answer my own question. One question, can I really put `const T&` as a template parameter? I tried it and I got an error about forming pointers to references. StoryTeller's answer about std::reference_wrapper works perfectly for me either way.

Comment: Just chiming in to say that `std::optional` explicitly disallowes references as the type it holds. The committee felt uneasy with *optional references* so that functionality didn't make it in from boost.

Comment: @StoryTeller and Willy: I was not aware of that, good to know! To be honest, I don't have a c++17 conforming compiler, so I always use boost::optional, I kind of naively assumed that what applies for that would also apply to std::optional.

Answer (score 4):

As clarified by your follow up comment, you are calling the function `foo` like this:

```
T t;
...
foo({t});
```

In this case, the answer is yes. A copy of `t` will be created. To avoid that, you can use `std::reference_wrapper` to avoid copying:

```
void foo(const std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const T>> &optT) {
    ...
}
```

With these changes to the function, calling the it in the same manner will not result in creation of a copy.

Comment: It doesn't really need to be a reference anymore: `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const T>> opt` will do the same thing.

One thing to beware of is this thing is too large to fit in a single register, so if you're calling this function a lot, it has many parameters and it's not inlined, you should probably use a simple pointer instead.

Actually you should just use a simple pointer instead IMO :)